# SDL Error Pops Up while opening apk

Tags: kivy

i managed to pack an app into an apk with buildozer using python2 but i get this error

```
an error occured whel trying to start the application. Please try again or reinstall.
Error: Couldn't load python3.5m from loader
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexpathList[zip
file"/data/a[[/prg.gp.gp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories-["/data/app-lib/org.go.go-1]/vendor/lib/system/lib]]:
```

findLibrary returned null

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Its unlikely anyone will know the answer with so little information. However it looks like there is something wrong with loading python3.5m

Comment: a popup appears and has this errors written within..so i cant seem to find where the error is coming from

Comment: Post the full log.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mtXFLb1q